# Is there OCR software that adapts to accented languages based on the Roman alphabet?

Tags: ocr

Many languages are now written using alphabets based on the Roman alphabet using various kinds of accenting systems. French and German might be the classic examples of European languages, but there are numerous others.

Have OCR products been written or adapted to fit at least some of these others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tesseract** is free software licensed under the Apache 2.0 license.

I use Tesseract with French mainly from the command line and I get good results. I did a quick test with Swedish (å, ä, ö, etc.) and Icelandic (á, ð, é, í, ú, ý, þ, æ, ö, etc.) - Latin-script alphabets plus extra letters. You have to install other languages. There's only English at first.

> **[Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract)** has unicode (UTF-8) support, and can recognize more than [100
> languages](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Data-Files-in-different-versions.html) "out of the box".
>
> This project does not include a GUI application. If you need one,
> please see the [3rdParty documentation](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/User-Projects-%E2%80%93-3rdParty.html).
>
> Tesseract can be trained to recognize other languages. See [Tesseract
> Training](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/) for more information.